# Salesforce Email Services dosen't work with Outlook or Lotus Notes

Tags: email, outlook, salesforce, lotus-notes

I have a Salesforce Email Service which accepts only text attachments.
Everything works fine till someone sends an email from Outlook or Lotus Notes.

My class doesn't even recognize a text attachment when sent from Outlook and Lotus Notes.
After careful research I found out that the text attachments are sent with the MIME Format of text/csv when I send an email from Gmail and in case of Outlook/Lotus Notes the format is  application/octet-stream.

Has anybody faced something similar and any suggestions to over come the situation?

Comment: Please clarify: is this 'Salesforce Email Service' something that you wrote? Something that you customized? Or is it a product provided to you off-the-shelf by Salesforce?

Comment: It is a Salesforce Email Service which I developed.

Comment: is there any code you can post?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Email Controller Class which is being used in the Email Service

```
global class CreativeDCoe_EmailHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
      Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

      System.debug('<<<<<< Starting Email Listener >>>>>>');   
      List<String> attInserted = new List<String>();
      List<String> attNotInserted = new List<String>();
      String csvBody = '';
      String strAttachmentName = '';
      String strEmailSubject = '';
      String strProgramID = '';
      Integer totalRecords = 0;
      String strDebugger = 'Logs<br /><br />';

      //Reading Email Subject Line to get the Program ID
      strEmailSubject = email.subject;
      strDebugger += 'Email Subject : <i>' + strEmailSubject + '</i><br />';
      System.Debug('<<<<<<< Email Subject : ' + strEmailSubject + ' >>>>>>>');
      //strProgramID = strEmailSubject.substring(strEmailSubject.indexOf(' : ') + 3, strEmailSubject.length()) ;
      strProgramID = strEmailSubject;
      strDebugger += 'Program ID : <i>' + strProgramID + '</i><br />';
      System.Debug('<<<<<<< Program ID : ' + strProgramID + ' >>>>>>>');

      String[] filelines = new String[]{};
      List<Program_Assessment_PA__c> attPADataList = new List<Program_Assessment_PA__c>();
      List<Data__c> fy;
      Boolean flag = false;

      if(email.textAttachments != null) 
      {

      //List<User> usr = [SELECT ID, Name, Email FROM User WHERE Email =: email.fromAddress LIMIT 1];

      //if(usr.size() > 0)
      if(true)
      {
          //strDebugger += 'Email sent from : <i>' + usr[0].Name + ' (' + usr[0].Email + ')</i><br />';
          //System.Debug('<<<<<<< ' + usr[0].Name + ' >>>>>>>');
          try {

              List<Program__c> program = [SELECT Name, ID, Program_Name__c FROM Program__c WHERE Name =: strProgramID ];

              if (program.size() > 0)
              {
                  strDebugger += 'Program found on records : <i>' + program[0].Name + ' (' + program[0].Program_Name__c + ')</i><br />';


                      System.Debug('<<<<<<< Email Attachments (TEXT) found. >>>>>>>');
                      strDebugger += 'Total Number of text attachments : <i>' + email.textAttachments.size() + '</i><br />';

                      fy = [SELECT Name, ID FROM Data__c WHERE Name =: String.valueOf(system.today().year())  LIMIT 1];

                      if(fy.size() == 0)
                      {
                          Data__c newFy = new Data__c (Name = String.valueOf(system.today().year()));
                          insert(newFy);
                          System.Debug('<<<<<<< FY Inserted. >>>>>>>');
                          fy[0] = newFY;
                          System.Debug('<<<<<<< FY : ' + fy[0].Name + ' >>>>>>>');      
                      }

                      System.Debug('<<<<<<< Total number of Text Attachments : ' + email.textAttachments.size() + ' >>>>>>>');                                                        

                      for (integer j = 0 ; j < email.textAttachments.size() ; j++)
                      {
                            strAttachmentName = email.textAttachments[j].filename.trim();
                            strDebugger += '<br />Text attachment <i>' + (j + 1) + '</i> : <i>' + strAttachmentName + '</i><br />';
                            System.Debug('<<<<<<< ' + (j+1) + ' Attachment Name : ' + strAttachmentName + ' >>>>>>>');
                            system.debug('<<<<<<< Extension of file : ' + strAttachmentName.substring(strAttachmentName.length() - 4, strAttachmentName.length()) + ' >>>>>>>');

                            // checking if the file is a csv file
                            if((strAttachmentName.contains('.csv')) && (strAttachmentName.substring(strAttachmentName.length() - 4, strAttachmentName.length()) == '.csv'))
                            {
                                attPADataList.clear();
                                csvBody = email.textAttachments[j].body;
                                System.Debug('<<<<<<< Total characters in the CSV file : ' + csvBody.length() + ' >>>>>>>'); 

                                filelines = csvBody.split('\n');
                                strDebugger += 'Total data lines in the CSV file : <i>' + (filelines.size() - 1) + '</i><br /><br />';
                                System.Debug('<<<<<<< Total data lines in the CSV file : ' + (filelines.size() - 1) + ' >>>>>>>');
                                for (Integer i = 1;i < filelines.size();i++)
                                {
                                    String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
                                    inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');
                                    strDebugger += 'Total input values for line <i> ' + i + ' </i>are : <i>' + inputvalues.size() + '</i><br />';
                                    System.Debug('<<<<<<< Total input values are : ' + inputvalues.size() + ' >>>>>>>'); 

                                    if(inputvalues.size() != 0)
                                    {

                                        Program_Assessment_PA__c newPALineItem = new Program_Assessment_PA__c();

                                        System.Debug('<<<<<<< Line : ' + i + ' >>>>>>>');
                                        System.Debug(filelines[i]);

                                        newPALineItem.Fiscal_Year__c = fy[0].ID;
                                        newPALineItem.Date__c = system.today();
                                        newPALineItem.Program_ID__c = program[0].ID;


                                        if(isNotNull(inputvalues[0])){
                                            newPALineItem.Question_ID__c = inputvalues[0].trim();
                                            flag = true;
                                        }

                                        if(isNotNull(inputvalues[1])){
                                            newPALineItem.Objective__c = inputvalues[1].trim();
                                            flag = true;
                                        }

                                        if(isNotNull(inputvalues[2])){
                                            newPALineItem.Dimension__c = inputvalues[2].trim();
                                            flag = true;
                                        }
                                        // there are some other columns 

                                        if(flag) {
                                            System.Debug('<<<<<<< Line item number ' + i + ' added to list. >>>>>>>');
                                            attPADataList.add(newPALineItem);
                                            flag = false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                System.Debug('<<<<<<< Inserting ' + attPADataList.size() + ' records to the PA Object >>>>>>>');
                                totalRecords += attPADataList.size();
                                insert attPADataList;
                                attInserted.add(strAttachmentName);

                            }

                            else
                            {
                                attNotInserted.add(strAttachmentName);
                            }
                        }

                        strDebugger += '<br />Total CSV\'s inserted : <i>' + attInserted.size() + '</i><br />';
                        System.Debug('<<<<<<< Total CSV\'s inserted : ' + attInserted.size());
                        if(attInserted.size() > 0)
                        {
                            //confirmation email message to the sender and support
                            String strSuccessHtmlBody = 'Hi, <br /> The Email Listener has successfully inserted ' + totalRecords + ' records to the Program Assessment (PA) from the following CSV files : <br /><br /><b>' + attInserted + '</b><br /><br /> Sender\'s Email ID : ' + email.fromAddress + '<br /> Subject Line : ' + email.subject + '<br /><br /><br /> Thanks, <br /> Email Listener Service <br/><br/><br/>' + '<br /><br /><br />' + strDebugger ;
                            String strSuccessEmailSubject = 'DCOE E-Mail Listener : Success';
                            System.debug('<<<<<<< DCOE Email Listener SUCCESS >>>>>>> ');
                            sendEmail(email.fromAddress, strSuccessHtmlBody, strSuccessEmailSubject); 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Non CSV attachment email message to the sender and support
                            String strNonCSVHtmlBody = 'Hi, <br /> The Email Listener failed to insert records from the following attachment(s) : <br /><br /><b>' + attNotInserted + '</b><br /><br /> Only CSV files are allowed for data import. <br /> Please re try with correctly formatted CSV file. ' + '<br /><br /> Sender\'s Email ID : ' + email.fromAddress + '<br /> Subject Line : ' + email.subject + '<br /><br /><br /> Thanks, <br /> Email Listener Service' + '<br /><br /><br />' + strDebugger ;
                            String strNonCSVEmailSubject = 'DCOE E-Mail Listener : Error - Non CSV Attachment(s) are not Accepted';
                            System.debug('<<<<<<< DCOE Email Listener No CSV Attachment(s) Found >>>>>>> ');
                            sendEmail(email.fromAddress, strNonCSVHtmlBody, strNonCSVEmailSubject); 
                        }       
                    }

                    else
                    {
                    //No Program found email message to sender and support
                    String strNoProgramHtmlBody = 'Hi, <br /> The Email Listener failed to insert records through the attachment(s). <br /><br /> There was no Program with program ID \'<i>' + strProgramID + '\'</i> found.' + '<br /><br /> Sender\'s Email ID : ' + email.fromAddress + '<br /> Subject Line : ' + email.subject + '<br /><br /><br /> Thanks, <br /> Email Listener Service' + '<br /><br /><br />' + strDebugger ;
                    String strNoProgramEmailSubject = 'DCOE E-Mail Listener : Error - No Matching Program Found';
                    System.debug('<<<<<<< DCOE Email Listener No Program Found >>>>>>> ');
                    sendEmail(email.fromAddress, strNoProgramHtmlBody, strNoProgramEmailSubject);
                    }  
                }

                       catch (Exception e)
            {
                        //exception email message to sender and support
                        String strErrorHtmlBody = 'Hi, <br /> The Email Listener failed to insert records from the CSV file ' + strAttachmentName + '.<br /><br /> Sender\'s Email ID : ' + email.fromAddress + '<br /> Subject Line : ' + email.subject + '<br />Following is the exception occured : ' + e + '<br />Please check paramenters like Subject and attach a correctly formatted CSV file before re-sending.<br />' + '<br /><br /><br /> Thanks, <br /> Email Listener Service' + '<br /><br /><br />' + strDebugger ;
                        String strErrorEmailSubject = 'DCOE E-Mail Listener : Error';
                        System.debug('<<<<<<< DCOE Email Listener Exception >>>>>>> ' + e);
                        sendEmail(email.fromAddress, strErrorHtmlBody, strErrorEmailSubject);                  
            }


                    }

                    else

          {
              // Denial email message to sender and support
              String strDeniedHtmlBody = 'Hi, <br /> You are not permissible to use this Email Listener service. <br /> No records were inserted from the CSV file ' + strAttachmentName + '.<br /><br /> Sender\'s Email ID : ' + email.fromAddress + '<br /> Subject Line : ' + email.subject + '<br /><br /><br /> Thanks, <br /> Email Listener Service' + '<br /><br /><br />' + strDebugger ;          
              String strDeniedEmailSubject = 'DCOE E-Mail Listener : Error - You are not allowed to create records.';
              System.debug('<<<<<<< DCOE Email Listener Denied User for Entry of Records>>>>>>>');
              sendEmail(email.fromAddress, strDeniedHtmlBody, strDeniedEmailSubject);

          }   
            }
          else
                    {
                        //No Attachments found email message to sender and support
                        String strNoAttachmentHtmlBody = 'Hi, <br /> The Email Listener failed to insert records through the attachment(s). <br /><br /> There were no text attachment(s) found on the email. <br /><br /> Sender\'s Email ID : ' + email.fromAddress + '<br /> Subject Line : ' + email.subject + '<br /><br /><br /> Thanks, <br /> Email Listener Service' + '<br /><br /><br />' + strDebugger ;
                        String strNoAttachmentEmailSubject = 'DCOE E-Mail Listener : Error - No Attachment(s) Found';
                        System.debug('<<<<<<< DCOE Email Listener No Attachment(s) Found >>>>>>> ');
                        sendEmail(email.fromAddress, strNoAttachmentHtmlBody, strNoAttachmentEmailSubject); 
                    }

        return result;
    }

    public void sendEmail(String strFromEmailAddress, String strHtmlBody, String strEmailSubject)
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
        String contactEmail = strFromEmailAddress;
        System.debug(strHtmlBody);
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {contactEmail} );
        mail.setSubject(strEmailSubject);
        mail.setHtmlBody(strHtmlBody);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

    }

    public Boolean isNotNull(String str) {
        return (str != null && str != '');
    }
}
```